# Why can't this template argument be deduced?

Tags: c++, templates

The parameters for Foo have default values, therefore in main() I can do Foo(); to create a Foo and it'll have the default template arguments. However I cannot use  in a template argument:

```
template <typename T = double, int a =2, int b = 3>
struct Foo {};


//cannot deduce template arguments for ‘Foo’ from ()
template <typename FooType = Foo()>   // <-- Error
struct TemplatedStructTakingAFooType
{

};

int main()
{
    Foo(); // Foo type is deduced to be default values, ie.,
    //Foo<double, 2, 3>;
    decltype(Foo()); // Compiler knows the type
}
```

In my Visual Studio compiler it highlights the area in red indicating an error, but compiles. On onlineGDB under C++17 is fails to compile with the above error. Is this allowed? Is there any reason it shouldn't be?

Edit: I realised how stupid using  is as Foo() isn't a type, but neither '= Foo' nor '= decltype(Foo())' work either.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Still doesn't work on OnlineGDB, I'll try get a link: https://onlinegdb.com/2uWTCJUIO

Comment: `template <typename FooType = Foo<>()>` works https://godbolt.org/z/PofM4Erx9

Comment: @JerryJeremiah What are the parentheses doing in that? I would understand `<typename FooType = Foo<>>` but `Foo<>()`? Evidently it does work but I don't understand how.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Thanks that got me on the right track! :)

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Could you explain that? That's like doing <typename IntType = int()> ? Why does that work? 'int()' isn't a type, it's a value-initialised int object/value

Comment: `template <typename FooType = Foo<>>` does work https://godbolt.org/z/TGb5cvrvj

Comment: I know the version with just `Foo<>` also works, I don't understand why the `Foo<>()` version works.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I'm confused for the same reason Nathan is, and also why template <typename IntType = int()>  works, 'int()' isn't a type, right?

Comment: `decltype(Foo());` is like `int;`. It won't compile.

Comment: @NathanPierson I think ir doesn't do what I expected.  It compiles but the type is Foo<>() which is a function taking no parameters and returning a Foo<>:  So  `template <typename FooType = Foo<>()>` is the same as `template <typename FooType = Foo<>(void)>`  and the correct answer is `template <typename FooType = Foo<>>` or `template <typename FooType = decltype(Foo())>` like the answer below.  https://godbolt.org/z/8fnhnqaqj

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well I understand why Foo() doesn't work, that was a dumb mistake of mine, Foo() isn't a type. So it shouldn't work. But int() isn't a type either, so why does that work?

Comment: @Zebrafish  Foo<>() is a function taking no parameters and returning a Foo<> and int() is a function taking no parameters and returning an int.  Both are types  - just not the type you were looking for.  So you can use Foo<> or decltype(Foo()) like the answer below suggests.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Wow, int() is a function? I know about the most vexing parse which can make it ambiguous between function declarations and constructor calls, but I expected int() to be the same the int() in void func(int defaultvalue = int() );

Comment: @Zebrafish  Well `template <typename FooType = Foo<>()>` produces the same exact type as `template <typename FooType = Foo<>(void)>` I guess the compiler knows that a type is expected and a constructor call wouldn't produce a type so it assumes it is a function declaration...  Otherwise, I have no idea how to explain the third and fourth output from https://godbolt.org/z/8fnhnqaqj

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `Foo` isn't a type, it's a *template* of a type.

You need to specify an actual type here, which needs the template angle-brackets, `Foo<>` which is the type `Foo<double, 2, 3>`:

```
typename FooType = Foo<>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, that makes complete sense, "Foo isn't a type, it's a template of a type". By the way the solution by Jerry Jeremiah I don't get, and he didn't explain it, in <typename FooType = Foo<>()>      'Foo<>()' isn't a type, that's like doing typename IntType = int() , which also works strangely, even though int() isn't a type.

Comment: @Zebrafish `int()` is a type (of functions with no arguments returning `int`).

Comment: int() is both a type and an expression. In this case the type is chosen
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters

Answer (score 3):

`Foo()` is not a type so need `decltype`:

```
typename FooType = decltype(Foo())
```

Comment: Hi. That makes sense. I made the dumb mistake of using typename FooType = Foo(), but decltype doesn't work either https://onlinegdb.com/HxujYBmcc

Comment: @Zebrafish: it does work . which compiler you're using ?? Try with higher version

Comment: @Zebrafish gcc11 should be fine Have tried

Comment: @nhatnq The code at https://godbolt.org/z/v6h3x1593 (identical to the code at onlinegdb.com/HxujYBmcc from a previous comment) works but I don't know why it gets a different result than you did.

Comment: @Zebrafish this error came from compiler. Anyway it was fixed in the later version

Answer (score 0):

Something will have to change because you're mixing ideas.

You can pass Foo as either

1. a type parameter,
2. a template parameter
3. a user defined non-type template parameter (New in C++20)

Here's an example of each:

```
template <typename T = double, int a =2, int b = 3>
struct Foo {};

// As a type.  The caller has secided what the template arguments that Foo
// will have, or by allowing them to default, has chosen the defaults.
template <typename FooType = decltype(Foo{})>
struct A
{
};

// Here FooType is passed as a template.  Inside B, you'd need to 
// provide it template parameters to instantiate it.
template <template <typename T, int, int> typename Foo2 = Foo>
struct B
{
    using F = Foo2<float, 3, 4>;
};

// As a user-defined non-type template parameter
// This only works in C++20, since it's a new feature
template <Foo f>
struct C
{
};

// And finally, CTAD to with deduced arguments for Foo as a user-defined
// non-type tempalte parameter, with friendly constructor syntax.  (For the
// caller, not for the reader of this monstrosity).
// The deduction guide allows passing an instance of Foo<T, a, b> to the
// constructor and allowing it to match types for T, a, b for the struct.
template <typename T, int a, int b, Foo<T, a, b> f>
struct D
{
    D(Foo<T, a, b>) { }
};
template <typename T, int a, int b> D(Foo<T, a, b>) -> D<T, a, b, Foo<T, a, b>{}>;

int main()
{
    A a;                      // default
    A<Foo<float, 5, 9>> a2;   // give types to Foo given to A

    B<Foo> b;                 // Pass Foo to b as a template-template param

    C<Foo{}> c;               // Pass instance of Foo with default args

    Foo<short, 99, 0> customFoo;
    D d(customFoo);           // Pass instance to constructor(!) to 
                              // set template args even when Foo is not default.
}
```

See it live: https://godbolt.org/z/8MGcn6zjj